How to secure data stored in Android Jetpack AppSearch local storage
Right now we use room database to cache certain metadata in it for later access. To keep the database secure, we use SQLCipher(https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android) to encrypt the database.
If I wanted to switch/introduce Jetpack AppSearch(https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/search/appsearch) for advanced search capabilities and use LocalStorage provided from them, how would you suggest to keep the data secure same way? e.g. encrypt the stored Documents etc.
Thank you in advance.

I don't think that you can directly influence the database that is internally used by AppSearch. I'm also not aware that AppSearch can be configured to encrypt its database itself.
